# Connecting to mongodb instance on google app engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am trying to open the mongodb instance I created using the compute engine cloud launcher so that I can access it from anywhere. Can you help me understand what is going wrong here?

## gcloud config set project my-project

## gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-mongo-arbiter --description      "Incoming mongo allowed." --target-tags=mongo-arbiter --allow tcp:27017

```
Created [allow-mongo].
NAME        NETWORK SRC_RANGES RULES     SRC_TAGS            TARGET_TAGS
allow-mongo-arbiter default            tcp:27017              mongo-arbiter
```

## gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-mongo-server --description "Incoming mongo allowed." --target-tags=mongo-server --allow tcp:27017

```
Created [allow-mongo-server].
NAME               NETWORK SRC_RANGES RULES     SRC_TAGS           TARGET_TAGS
allow-mongo-server default            tcp:27017                    mongodb-server
```

When I ssh to the mongo server, 27017 is listening. Tried resetting the VMs

There is no port open: telnet  27017 does not connect

Comment: You should use target tags to allow instances tagged with mongodb-server to accept connections on 27017. Can you confirm that the server instances have this tag? Also, can you confirm your arbiter instance has tag mongo-arbiter and is making connections on other instances via port 21707? Is there a particular guide you're following right now?

Comment: Thanks ! I was using the wrong tags. I can connect now. I thought tags were same as name of instance whereas they are dynamic.

Comment: I've posted the solution as an answer, please accept! Glad to hear it's working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the tags were not attached to the instances. Always good to have another anonymous user sanity-check the things we don't expect~!!